# Fix "unbalanced grouping command" Doxygen warnings

Tags: doxygen

Our Doxygen build in ITK is raising a number of "unbalanced grouping commands" warnings:
https://open.cdash.org/viewBuildError.php?type=1&buildid=8335387

Following the warning description I am guessing that these might be due to a potential improper use of "\ingroup" commands in our files, or the impossibility to correctly interpret them the way we define our groups.

Besides the [code modules that we parse as groups](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/CMake/ITKGroups.cmake), we [define a number of other groups](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Documentation/Doxygen/Modules.dox).

That give rise (using a [GitHub actions workflow](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKDoxygen%20repository)) to the modules shown in:
https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/modules.html

Despite the warnings, many of these filters seem to display the modules/groups they belong to correctly in the header of the file, e.g.

`Data Processing Objects » FunctionsData Processing Objects » Functions » Image Functions » | Image InterpolatorsGroup Core » | Module ITKCommon`

https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BSplineInterpolationWeightFunction.html

However, we would like to remove the warnings and get a clean build, so I am wondering how to fix the warnings.

We have an [ITK issue](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/issues/3654) that may be useful for anyone trying to help.

Thanks.

Code inspection to locate grouping commands that are not properly closed.

Comment: First question is which doxygen version are you using? I've seen references to 1.8.16 and 1.9.3, though the current version is 1.9.5, advise is to update to 1.9.5 for sure. The warning 'warning: unbalanced grouping commands` typically refers to code parts like `/* @{` and `/*@}`, in the past these were correct but the `/*` refers to "normal" comment an not to doxygen comment so this has been corrected and one has to use doxygen types of comments (like `/**`). As far as I can see this has been done in version 1.8.16 (released August 8, 2019).

Comment: See also discussion at https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/issues/3654

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @albert.

We are using Doxygen 1.8.16. We'll look at updating it.

Thanks for the information concerning the `/*` vs `/**` distinction. It may actually be that we are using the former.